# How should I link a CSS file for the subdomain from the main domain?

Tags: html, css

I may be using subdomains incorrectly here instead of using sub directories, but I want to import the same CSS into my subdomain (hire.joeisaacson.com) from my main domain (joeisaacson.com)

The current file structure is below

```
public_html (where joeisaacson.com points to)
-index.html
-css
--style.css
-hire (where hire.joeisaacson.com points to)
--index.html
```

I want to access style.css from the "hire" folder instead of creating a duplicate and having to updated both.

using ../css/style.css from the "hire" folder doesn't work, because it searches within hire.joeisaacson.com and not joeisaacson.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you have a case that the same source code will be used at different nesting levels (like /index.htm and /hire/index.htm or different domains you might want to consider the [HTML BASE tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.4).

```
<base href="http://joeisaacson.com">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

This will fetch the CSS from `http://joeisaacson.com/css/style.css` regardless of where the HTML page is served as long as you realise it will do this for all external resources (images, css, js, etc).

Just be sure `BASE` tag is inside `HEAD` and comes before any linked content. You also do not close this tag in HTML (so no `</base>` or `<base />` is expected)

Comment: Interesting. So this will pull the most recent version of style.css that's up live on joeisaacson.com? 

It looks like referencing it is not going to work. Thanks @spliFF

Comment: Correct. The browser will actually ask for `http://joeisaacson.com/css/style.css` not `http://hire.joeisaacson.com/hire/css/style.css` or whatever it is pulling now. This will happen for all linked resources starting with `/` (absolute) or an url with no scheme/host part (relative - eg: css/styles.css). These paths are now relative to the BASE HREF and not guessed from the current URL.

Comment: You cannot believe how hard it has been to find this information which surely must be required often. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you should provide absolute path in that case for including on subdomain. It should be looking something like :

```
http://joeisaacson.com/css/style.css
```

Comment: That's what I have done now as a hack (view hire.joeisaacson.com) 

But I want to be able to edit those CSS files without having to push live to my server every time just to see the changes.

Comment: As you are cross-referencing between domain and sub-domain, I do not see any other option to achieve it. If you want to edit it for particularly subdomain changes then I would suggest to have a copy of it in subdomain and change it.