# Rename the url of the translated html files in the root (htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url

I am building a web app and trying to add two languages to the website. So I will make the same documents ending in -gr. Some examples of the files look like this:

**English Language paths:**

> www.example.com/index.html
>   
>  www.example.com/Blog.html

**Greek Language path:**

> www.example.com/index-gr.html
>   www.example.com/Blog-gr.html

Is that possible to rename the greek files to something like the following example:

**www.example.com/blog-gr.html/**

should be renamed to

**www.example.com/blog/gr**

eg: Remove the -gr.html of all the greek documents and add /gr at the end.
Also only for index file,  example.com/index-gr.html should be example.com/gr
Thanks

Comment: In your edited question, you really want to rename the file from `index-gr.html` to `index.html/gr` (what I guessed) or just want to rewrite the url (which I've already done).

Comment: @lkdhruw I want to rename all greek files ending with -gr.html to .html/gr. Also only 1 file (the homepage) example.com/index-gr.html should be example.com/gr

Comment: I think the problem is with all the relative URLs because your base changed from domoin.com to domain.com/index.html/. You can try adding `base` tag in your homepage `<base href="http://www.example.com/page.html">`. See more https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: I added <base href="https://gragop.herokuapp.com/index-gr.html"> in the index-gr.html file but same thing

Comment: Can't help you much. Try `<base href="https://gragop.herokuapp.com">` as your base tag given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998245/how-should-i-link-a-css-file-for-the-subdomain-from-the-main-domain

Comment: I think your site is ok now with this url https://gragop.herokuapp.com/index.html/gr. If you've made some modifications then let us know.

Comment: I did nothing more, I just added the base tag in the greek file. When I click again on the greek flag the url changes again to the index-gr.html :/

Comment: @lkdhruw Do you know how to rename the ...com/index-gr.html to just  ...com/gr  ?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^gr$ index-gr.html [NC,L]` Add this line above your other rewrite rule

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)/gr$ greek/$1 [NC,L]
```

**EDIT**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html/gr$ $1-gr.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: gonna try it on heroku. I hope this works on subodmains

Comment: If won't work try after reopening the browser or try in the different browser. this happened to me.

Comment: The other option is to move the translated files into the same directory as the English documents and rename them to something like index-gr.html and just rename those files something like index.html/gr

Comment: only one file is in php the index.php

Comment: If you want to rewrite url for only html files then add the corresponding line other won't be affected.

Comment: I will edit my question since I moved the files to the same directory, edit yours as well after mine to find a solution

Comment: all greek files are in .html so no point to replace any file in php

Comment: so depending on my updated question which is your correct code?

Comment: I worked but unfortunately not as expected. other files (html/js/css) with relative url has got affected.