# Remove file extension in apache 2.4

Tags: php, apache

I want to refer to a page without the .php extension and not to use the .htaccess file, as a documentation says:

> You should avoid using .htaccess files completely if you have access
>   to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server.

Comment: Have you tried anything or do you have a particular budget in mind if you want to pay us to do it for you? The documentation says that you should but your rewrite rules in the main server config rather than htaccess files. It's done the same way.

Comment: That's the weirdest advice I've ever read. You want to use .htaccess files for sites if you ever want to move them around on servers and not constantly fiddle with the main configuration of each webserver. Having directory specific configurations all in one place is a good way of stopping any continuous deployment setup.

Comment: just add code in your `.htaccess` for this

Comment: What shoud i write in .htaccess file?

Comment: read my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893119/rename-the-url-of-the-translated-html-files-in-the-root-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write the configuration you want (a "rewrite rule" in your case I think) in the virtual host of your website to avoid the .htaccess. See the doc here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use `.htaccess` then you can use the following directly in the server config (or `<VirtualHost>` container).

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* `!\.\w{2,4}$` ensures that only requests that do not already contain a file extension are processed (so static resources are naturally excluded).

The *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) ensures that the target `.php` file exists before rewriting the request.

Note that this doesn't strictly "remove" the file extension. It allows extensionless URLs to work by internally rewriting the request to append the `.php` file extension so it maps to the underlying `.php` file. You need to actually "remove" the `.php` extension in your HTML source.

(This rule will also work unaltered in `.htaccess` if required.)

NB: If you are not using `.htaccess` then you should ensure that `.htaccess` overrides are completely disabled, otherwise the server will still search for them and you will not get the full benefit. (Although `.htaccess` files are really not that bad.)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason not using `.htaccess` for this

Use **.htaccess** to remove php extension:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

That's it, you can now link your pages without needing to add the php extension. E.g :

`<a href="http://example.com/index">Home</a>`