# How to access .html or .php file without extension on 127.0.0.1/

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

How to access my `.html` or `.php` file without extension?

This is my Folder structure:

```
C:\Apache24\htdocs\search-html\test
         search-html
           test
            low.html
            high.html
            new.html
```

My URL is `127.0.0.1/search-html/test/low.html`

But i want to access this URL like `127.0.0.1/search-html/test/low`

for running localhost server I use `httpd.exe -k` start on command prompt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove file extension in apache 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349644/remove-file-extension-in-apache-2-4)

Comment: Or this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781738/making-a-rewriterule-remove-php-extension

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `.htaccess` file to the document root to rewrite the url.

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

# Remove .php-extension from url
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php

 # Remove .html-extension from url
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules
</IfModule>
```

And if you want to add a trailing slash at the end you can add this bit.

```
# Add trailing slash to url
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: should I above code write in .htaccess file? And please let me know what will be the document root?

Comment: You have to create a new file and the name of the file should be ``.htaccess``

Comment: And your document root should be ``C:\Apache24\htdocs\search-html\test``. So place the file in test folder.

Comment: I have created .htaccess file with the same code as written above and placed the file in test directory but it is not working without .html extension.                                      
Error:   Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: "Add trailing slash to url" - This is not stated in the question. In fact, the example URL given does not include a trailing slash.

Comment: My URL is : http://127.0.0.1/search-html/test/low.html and I am trying to run by giving : http://127.0.0.1/search-html/test/low

Comment: I updated my answer. You can do that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in your `.htaccess` file. It doesn't really matter where the `.htaccess` file is located, providing it is inside the document root and somewhere along the file-path being requested.

If you are requesting URLs of the form `http://127.0.0.1/search-html/test/low` then `C:\Apache24\htdocs` is your `DocumentRoot` (looking at your "folder structure"), as defined in the server config.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Append ".html" extension if the file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

# Otherwise append ".php" extension if the file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.php -f
RewriteRule !\.\w{2,4}$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

The above rules specifically exclude any URL that already includes what looks-like a file extension. So static resources (images, JS and CSS, etc.) will naturally be excluded.

Alternatively, if you are doing nothing else in `.htaccess` and want extensionless URLs then just enable MultiViews. For example:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

However, this does have some caveats:

- Extensionless URLs are essentially enabled on *everything*, not just `.html` and `.php` files. Including images, JS and CSS etc.
- If you later want to do more complex URL rewriting with mod_rewrite then you may need to *disable* MultiViews and use the mod_rewrite solution instead. MultiViews and mod_rewrite can result in unexpected conflicts.